# How to save one record for multiple department using core data in swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have two tables name **Employee** & **Department**, I have given relationship like following ways,

See bellow my Department table

[image]

& this is my Employee table

[image]

```
   func saveEmpDetails(empId: String, andEmployeeName empName: String, andDeptId deptId: String, andDeptName departName: String, andProfile profileName: String, createdOn minutesAgo:Double , empQuote quote:String) {

            // Reading AppDelegate
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            // Getting managed object context
            let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let empID:Int? = Int(empId)

            let _predicate = NSPredicate(format: "empId=%@", empId)

            let _fetchRecord: Employee? = isRecordExist(withEntiryName: "Employee", with: _predicate) as? Employee


            if _fetchRecord != nil {

                // Update Employee record as managed objext


            }else {

                // Inserting Employee record as managed objext
                let _empInformation: Employee? = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Employee", into: managedObjectContext) as? Employee

                _empInformation?.empId = Int32(empID!)
                _empInformation?.empName = empName
                _empInformation?.empProfile = profileName
                _empInformation?.createdOn = Date().addingTimeInterval(-minutesAgo * 60) as NSDate
                _empInformation?.empQuote = quote

                let departmentRecord: Department? = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Department", into: managedObjectContext) as? Department
                //            departmentRecord?.departName = departName
                //            departmentRecord?.departId = Int32(deptId)!
                //            departmentRecord?.addToEmployees(_empInformation!)

                let allDepartments = NSSet(array : ["10", "11"])  // Set<String>
                departmentRecord?.addToEmployees(allDepartments)
                departmentRecord?.addToEmployees(_empInformation!)
            }

            // Saving the employee details using save context
            appDelegate.saveDBContext()
        }
```

> Now i want to save the one record for multiple departments, lets assume `ABC` employee work in **iOS** department & **Android**

**My Question is :** how can i save that `ABC`employee record at one time. I have given my lot of efforts & did stack-overflow but didn't come across such a condition.

Can anyone help to complete my tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your employee relationship from 'to one' to 'to many' so that the relationship between the two entities becomes 'many to many'. Then your employee will have a Set of departments. Just look up many to many core data relationships, there's a lot of info about it out there.

Comment: This is your answer OP, you will then be able to use `employee.ofDepartment.allObjects` to get a array of the departments that your employee is a part of

Comment: Even i tried this but not able to achieve exact thing, do you have any demo or tutorial please?